# amazon scraping from beautifulsoup differs from using a browser

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from the search results of amazon.com

now, for the same keyword(s), amazon returns a list of results displayed in a `<ul>` tag.

each `<li>` tag contains a product in the results.

when you do the keyword search from a browser, you'd get that list say of 15 results, in which the last 2 or 3 `<li>`s are "sponsored" ads of products in that listing.

however, doing the same thing from python using beautifulsoup, I only get the `<li>`s which are not a "sponsored" ad

I made sure that I'm not missing the tag, by printing the whole soup in a file and searched throught it.

here's the python code running bs4 (you wouldn't find it very helpful in identifying the problem, I'm pretty sure it's something related to amazon somehow)

```
def get_asins_in_page(soup, sponsored):
    asins_dict = {}
    asins_sponsored_dict = {}
    reslist = soup.find("ul", {"id": "s-results-list-atf"})
    for r in reslist.find_all('li'):
        asins_dict[r.get('data-asin')] = r.get('id')
    return asins_dict

def find_ranking_by_asin(keyword, target_asin, sponsored):
    print "%s %s"%(keyword, target_asin)
    loop_count = 0
    url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+urllib.quote(keyword)
    while True:
        loop_count+=1
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        url ="http://www.amazon.com" + soup.find("a",{"id":"pagnNextLink"}).get('href') #next_page_url 
        asins_dict = get_asins_in_page(soup, False)
        if target_asin in asins_dict:
            return asins_dict[target_asin].replace("result_","")    
        #fail-safe:
        if loop_count > 50:
            return -1
```

I come from a data science background, so I'm not much of a web developer. it might be that I'm missing something to tell amazon that I'm coming from a web browser of some kind!

EDIT: 
I added the headers to the request, and still no luck with that.

here's the modified code with headers (I tried removing the cookie and keeping everything, didn't matter):

```
def get_asins_in_page(soup, sponsored):
    asins_dict = {}
    asins_sponsored_dict = {}
    reslist = soup.find("ul", {"id": "s-results-list-atf"})
    for r in reslist.find_all('li'):
        print r.findAll('h5')
        asins_dict[r.get('data-asin')] = r.get('id')
    return asins_dict

def find_ranking_by_asin(keyword, target_asin, sponsored):
    print "%s %s"%(keyword, target_asin)
    loop_count = 0
    headers = {
            'Accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6',
            'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0',
            'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
            'Cookie' : """x-wl-uid=1sKNa/Tu+dnJiObdvPzWmOWvHoQHs7SbunE2P1wtUNyXZoFmxflkD74oIUtjg6je4M1DNJgid9D73eSQ/1szSzyViGKhQNfYhzyrIF+0sYuCypgc4oFkknUPA4xZ0Aeienl0XdGyC/GE=; bhqns=d0sdm59meaki4gsmq4gsdpv5k3; x-main="HSxQRguP7RaA0XNnOlvYoSu?jhNN?Gbu"; b2b-main=0; s_vnum=1857890451251%26vn%3D3; appstore-devportal-locale=en_US; aws_lang=en; aws-target-data=%7B%22support%22%3A%221%22%7D; s_dslv=1428249404729; aws-target-visitor-id=1428249404407-552911.26_29; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; _mkto_trk=id':'810-GRW-452&token':'_mch-amazon.com-1428249580944-19910; __utma=194891197.1337326270.1428250257.1428250257.1428250257.1; __utmc=194891197; __utmz=194891197.1428250257.1.1.utmccn=(referral)|utmcsr=google.com.eg|utmcct=/|utmcmd=referral; pN=1; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D3E166C526619A613-1D8EA49490B2AAB8%7C1491407981003%3B%20s_dl%3D1%7C1428251381006%3B%20gpv_page%3DUS%253AAS%253APADS-how-it-works%7C1428251381011%3B%20s_ev15%3D%255B%255B%2527NSGoogle%2527%252C%25271428249581020%2527%255D%255D%7C1586102381020%3B%20s_invisit%3Dtrue%7C1428252056959%3B%20s_nr%3D1428250256962-Repeat%7C1436026256962%3B; s_sess=%20c_m%3Dwww.google.com.egNatural%2520Search%3B%20s_ppvl%3DUS%25253AAS%25253APADS-how-it-works%252C56%252C56%252C955%252C1920%252C955%252C1920%252C1080%252C1%252CL%3B%20s_cc%3Dtrue%3B%20s_sq%3D%3B%20s_ppv%3DUS%25253AAS%25253APADS-how-it-works%252C91%252C56%252C1555%252C1920%252C955%252C1920%252C1080%252C1%252CL%3B; session-token=opZ2DsH3n42Pz4spSbxaz9oQx5kGTKq1pj4n5WE+pGWvRBk6IyjvUQWw/GrDH2dGqbwR7d97ibcno5K4B1yUnpoVceB8aEDziGrWpU+I+tHBkWWy0ZMorJZowa3DMS40gfMTAc1Gd/o4ZpYOibC1SPQEzU3Eg2OslDRNyys+e90lJaothbV12MO62XiHFsnjjhCVFk8Ztr3hRgnl5oC1NvbZ9lZ7QjmhDP9wXgnYmG6wevsgqdukBbKoohHv1kGOWg60CWLBFS/RhVqukMAO5g==; skin=noskin; ubid-main=182-4576256-0011665; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=180-4378028-6113727; csm-hit=1RPD28BQJKGVJNHSZKFR+s-1RPD28BQJKGVJNHSZKFR|1428854614288""",
            'Host' : 'www.amazon.com',
            'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537a'
            } 
    url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+urllib.quote(keyword)
    while True:
        loop_count+=1
        r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        url ="http://www.amazon.com" + soup.find("a",{"id":"pagnNextLink"}).get('href') #next_page_url 
        asins_dict = get_asins_in_page(soup, False)
        if target_asin in asins_dict:
            return asins_dict[target_asin].replace("result_","")

        #fail-safe:
        if loop_count > 50: return -1
```

Comment: It probably has to do with the `UserAgent`.

Comment: Probably the headers, yes. Press F12 in your browser go to network and check the values which been submited with the request. You could alternatively use 'requests.session' to set headers and save cookies if you want that.

Comment: I edited the question with the result of what you suggested, I added all the headers that are in the browser, still no luck with that.